# Zend_Soap_Server returns an empty soap message

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, soap, wsdl

I'm having an issue with a Zend_Soap_Server that I created. Somehow the server is returning this:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Date: Sat, 14 Jun 2014 07:39:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u10
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

The thing is, it should respond something. And with something I mean I should get back an identifier (see below).

What I have as code:

```
class MyShorts {

  [...]

  /**
   * Store a new URL into the database.
   * 
   * @param string The URL to store
   *
   * @return string the unique identifier for this URL
   * 
   * @exception for database errors.
   */
  public function store($url) {

    $db = $this->getDb();

    while ( true ) {
      try {
        $identifier = $this->getRandomIdentifier(5);
        $db->insert('urls', array('identifier' => $identifier,
                                  'long'       => $url,
                                  'created'    => new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'),
        ));

        return $identifier;
      }
      catch( Exception $e ) {
        throw $e;
      }
    }

    return '';
  }
```

As you can see here, it stores a url in the database, and returns the identifier. From what I can see is that in the database, it is stored correctly. So calling and stuff works fine.

It's just that I do not get the identifier back. How can that come?

Thanks!

BTW, how I handle the incoming requests:

```
$soap = new Zend_Soap_Server($WSDL);
$soap->setClass('MyShorts');
$soap->handle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the above described way did not work.
What did work however was this:

```
$soap = new Zend_Soap_Server(null, array('uri' => $WSDL));
```

Obviously $WSDL was the url to the soap base url, not the wsdl anymore...